# Activity leak due to FragmentController holds reference to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, fragment, out-of-memory

Attached is the snapshot of the HPROF file that I captured. You see on the left pane that MainActivity object is in Heap (this is leaked..there is another activity object not shown in picture) and on right is the instances that it is holding. One of them is

```
mFragments = {android.support.v4.app.FragmentControler@....."
```

This refers to mHost which inturn refers to 'this' which is MainActivity and also mActivity (MainActivity).

Each time I pressed back key on activity and launch app again, I see one activity is leaking. I resolved all other reference from my code (null referenced them in onDestroy()). But this mFragments is not from my code but from framework.

THere is similar of this kind:

mFragments = {android.app.FragmentManagerImpl@@....."

There are few other references like this. How should we make sure the activity is not being referenced from framework classes when activity is finished?

[image]